# Safari fails to render $window.document.title

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-browser

So i have a this in my angular js application:

```
.factory("titleService", function($window) {
  return {
    setPageTitle: function(title) {
        $window.document.title = title;
    }
  };
});

titleService.setPageTitle("My Title");
```

All browsers except Safari fails to render this title, instead full path of script is shown.

Comment: Is that inside a popup?

Comment: no, is not inside a pop up

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the call `titleService.setPageTitle("My Title");` inside a controller like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="stackoverflow">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('stackoverflow', []);
      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, titleService) {
        titleService.setPageTitle('StackOverflow');
      })

      .factory("titleService", function($window) {
        return {
          setPageTitle: function(title) {
              $window.document.title = title;
          }
        };
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Changed title to "StackOverflow"!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: inside the controller the call is made

Comment: Then you need to show non-working example code, the code I posted works and solves your question. In which situation is it not working?